# C++/CLI - .obj file generated from .cpp source file contains no symbols (LNK2020)

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

At the moment I'm working on implementing a managed wrapper in C++/CLI, for a native C library.

I have no hard experience with the language, and this week has been a sort of crash course while trying to complete my project. Although it has a few surprising and [frustrating quirks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442784/Best-gotchas-of-Cplusplus-CLI), there are plenty of good articles floating around.

Background:

- I have a class (`WrappedAvType`) declared in a `Common.h` and the class members are implemented in a corresponding `Common.cpp`, and they are both in the project root directory.
- Other files in the project are organized in their own directories, and include `..\Common.h` to access the class declaration it contains
- Environment: Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.1 x64, targeting .NET Framework 4.5, generating x86 binaries

**Common.h:**

```
#pragma once

namespace LibavDotNet {

    template<class T>
    public ref class WrappedAvType abstract
    {
    public:
        property bool IsDirty;
        WrappedAvType();
        WrappedAvType(T avObject);
        ~WrappedAvType();
        virtual T Unwrap();

    private:
        T _avObject;

    protected:
        virtual void SetAvObject(T avObject);
    };
}
```

**Common.cpp:**

```
#include "Common.h"

namespace LibavDotNet {

    template<class T>
    WrappedAvType<T>::WrappedAvType()
    {
        IsDirty = false;
    }

    template<class T>
    WrappedAvType<T>::WrappedAvType(T avObject)
    {
        _avObject = avObject;
    }

    template<class T>
    WrappedAvType<T>::~WrappedAvType()
    { }

    template<class T>
    T WrappedAvType<T>::Unwrap()
    {
        return _avObject;
    }

    template<class T>
    void WrappedAvType<T>::SetAvObject(T avObject)
    {
        _avObject = avObject;
    }
}
```

However I'm currently stumped (maybe blinded from staring at the code for too damn long...) with a peculiar problem: whenever I compile the project in its described state, I receive error `LNK2020` indicating that it no token can be found for `WrappedAvType`.

To confirm that the symbols were available in the generated binary, I used `dumpbin /symbols Common.obj` and in fact there don't appear to be any:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 11.00.61030.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file Common.obj

File Type: COFF OBJECT

COFF SYMBOL TABLE
000 00CFEE66 ABS    notype       Static       | @comp.id
001 80000191 ABS    notype       Static       | @feat.00
002 00000000 SECT1  notype       Static       | .drectve
    Section length   78, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
004 00000000 SECT2  notype       Static       | .debug$S
    Section length  35C, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
006 00000000 SECT3  notype       Static       | .debug$T
    Section length   7C, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0
008 00000000 SECT4  notype       Static       | .cormeta
    Section length  45C, #relocs    0, #linenums    0, checksum        0

String Table Size = 0x0 bytes

  Summary

         45C .cormeta
         35C .debug$S
          7C .debug$T
          78 .drectve
```

If I include the class implementation directly with `#include "..\Common.cpp"` in the other source files that need it (only one other so far), then the project compiles as expected.
At this point I have no idea what else to try and have searched for a solution for hours. I'd very much like to keep my headers with class declarations and source files with class implementations separate.

I fully expect this to be something minor that I've overlooked or that I'm just too green to notice. What am I missing?

Comment: Any reason you're not using `generic` instead of `template`?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti, yes: I need the class to wrap a native C ``struct`` or ``struct`` pointer and apparently ``generic<>`` doesn't support that.

Comment: Then you have to include cpp (or to provide everything inside .h). It's not a _problem_ with the managed class but what you have to do with _plain_ templates. Templates must be defined in each translation unit.

Comment: By the way, is this behaviour the same in C++ or is it exclusive to C++/CLI?

Comment: It's the same in _pure_ C++, that's why I asked if you can use generics: templates will create multiple classes for each usage and they can't be _exported_ as classes to, for example, a C# program without much more trouble (STL.NET docet...)

Comment: Thanks, that's great to know! :)
In hindsight the question doesn't seem to be as well researched as it could have been...If you're a moderator please feel free to lock/remove the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T>
```

This is a standard C++ problem, it doesn't have anything to do with C++/CLI.  Templates do not have external linkage.  The entire implementation of the template class must be present in the .h file.  Which is why the #include worked.

Do keep the strong code smell in mind, templates are a pure C++ feature.  Your wrapper isn't actually usable by any other .NET language, they don't support templates of course.  Only ref classes that are declared with the *generic* keyword are usable.

Comment: Yes, you're right. My error was assuming that templates in C++/CLI would function the same way as .NET generics...
What path would you suggest to solve this problem elegantly?
As I mentioned in my post, this is my first serious attempt at using C++ / C++/CLI and at making a wrapper for unmanaged code; I'd really appreciate some guidance from someone experienced with this subject.

Comment: I just have no idea why it needs to be a template and why a generic couldn't work, I can't tell from your code.  You'll have to ask another question about it.

Comment: I mentioned in the comment thread of my post: generics don't support native types, which is what I need to wrap.